# How to add correct number formatting to my Java program

Tags: java

When I run my program, the annual sales examples end with a $ instead of begin with a $ and only have 1 decimal place. Also, I cannot figure out had to add commas to the numbers. I am a beginner at Java, so I am not very skilled at all.

```
package salesman1;
/*
 * Annual Compensation Program
 * Created by: Big Werd
 *This program calculates the total compensation for a sales person based on the
 *amount of the yearly fixed income and the annual commission that was earned.
*/

public class Salesman1 {
    // fixed salary variable
     double fixedSalary;
     // amount of the annual sales for the salesman
     double  annualSales;
     //commission that was earned
     double commission;
     //The current sales goal
     double target;
     public Salesman1(double annualSales){
         this.annualSales=annualSales;
         target=120000;
         commission=0;
         if(annualSales>target*0.8){
            if(annualSales<target)commission=0.15*annualSales;//15% Commission is earned annually
            else commission=0.15*1.25*annualSales;//The acceleration factor is 1.25 
         }
         fixedSalary=35000;// set fixed salary is $35,000
     }
     public double getTotalAnnualCompensation(){// Fixed salary added to the commission earned for a calculation of the total compensation.
         return fixedSalary+commission;
     }
}

package salesman1;


import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * Annual Compensation Program
 * Created by: James Werderman
 *This program calculates the total compensation for a sales person based on the
 *amount of the yearly fixed income and the annual commission that was earned.
 */

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double annualSales;
        Salesman1 person;
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What were the total annual sales?: ");// Requests the annual sales amount
        annualSales=input.nextDouble();
        person=new Salesman1(annualSales);// creates a salesperson
        System.out.println(" The total annual compensation: "+String.format("%.2f", person.getTotalAnnualCompensation())+"$");
        System.out.println(" Total Sales Amount           Total Compensation Amount");
        annualSales=annualSales+5000;
        for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
            person=new Salesman1(annualSales);
             System.out.println(annualSales+"$                "+String.format("%.2f", person.getTotalAnnualCompensation())+"$");
            annualSales+=5000;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance())?

Comment: Where would I add this in my code?

Comment: Where ever you want to print a the number in it's formatted form...

Answer (score 2):

First, you're suffixing the result with `$`

```
System.out.println(annualSales + "$
```

This means that the `annualSales` value will be printed first and then the `$` symbol, switch them

```
System.out.println("$" + annualSales + "
```

You could also do something like...

```
System.out.printf(" $%17.2f | $%24.2f%n", annualSales, person.getTotalAnnualCompensation());
```

instead, this will print something like

```
 Total Sales Amount | Total Compensation Amount
 $          6000.00 | $                35000.00
 $         11000.00 | $                35000.00
 $         16000.00 | $                35000.00
 $         21000.00 | $                35000.00
 $         26000.00 | $                35000.00
 $         31000.00 | $                35000.00
 $         36000.00 | $                35000.00
 $         41000.00 | $                35000.00
 $         46000.00 | $                35000.00
 $         51000.00 | $                35000.00
 $         56000.00 | $                35000.00
```

Now, I'm not a fan of this, I'd like the `$` next to the text

Instead, I might be temptered to do something more like...

```
System.out.printf(" %18s | %25s%n", 
                        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(annualSales), 
                        NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(person.getTotalAnnualCompensation()));
```

Which prints...

```
 Total Sales Amount | Total Compensation Amount
          $6,000.00 |               $35,000.00
         $11,000.00 |               $35,000.00
         $16,000.00 |               $35,000.00
         $21,000.00 |               $35,000.00
         $26,000.00 |               $35,000.00
         $31,000.00 |               $35,000.00
         $36,000.00 |               $35,000.00
         $41,000.00 |               $35,000.00
         $46,000.00 |               $35,000.00
         $51,000.00 |               $35,000.00
         $56,000.00 |               $35,000.00
```

Now, you might be able to use `NumberFormat.getInstance` instead and mix the two approaches, allowing you to get the `$` along the left edge and the number, formatted, along the right, but that's up to you...

You might like to take a look [at this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) which gives more details about the `String` format specifications

Comment: Thank you very much MadProgrammer for taking the time to answer my question. Your answer not only providing me the information I requested but in turn taught me about formatting. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Normally, more than one way to skin this cat